# How to implement a baseclass for Symfony2 controllers

Tags: dependency-injection, symfony

There are some articles around which touch this topic, but none of them seemed to be a practical usable solution for me.
My goal is to put some basic methods (those I need in each controller anyway) into a basecontroller, e.g.

```
   $this->getEntityManager();
   $this->getRequest();
   $this->getRepository($entityName);
```

How can this be done?

AFAIK we have to inject the services into the basecontroller, but how do I tell classes to use a service for their superclass?
There is some decent article about Controllers and Dependency Injection [1], but finally I got stuck with that approach too, see my comment here: [2]

[1] http://miller.limethinking.co.uk/2011/04/15/symfony2-controller-as-service/

[2] http://miller.limethinking.co.uk/2011/04/15/symfony2-controller-as-service/#comment-579

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pseudocode

```
MyBaseController impliments Symfony\Component\Di\ContainerAwareInterface
  setContainer($container)
    $this->container = $container

  getEntityManager
    return $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager')
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. When I make use of the basecontroller i get following error message: "Fatal error: Declaration of ...Bundle\Controller\BaseController::setContainer() must be compatible with that of Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface::setContainer() in /Library/WebServer/Documents/...Bundle/Controller/BaseController.php on line 9". 

Setter looks like this:  

`function setContainer(\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface $container){
  $this->container = $container;
}`

Comment: `$container` can be null, so should be `(...\ContainerInterface$container = null)`

Comment: BAD IDEA.   It's like loading everything and saying it's lean.    I suggest you simply do an ``abstract class MyBaseController``  with ``protected`` methods.  But do not inject all stuff like this.   See ["problematic"'s post series "Controller in a diet"](http://iamproblematic.com/putting-your-symfony2-controllers-on-a-diet-part-2/) it explains  A LOT.